# Calculus 1 - Optimization Cylinder

Tags: calculus, optimization, volume

A  (right circular) cylindrical can has a volume of 60π cubic inches. Suppose that the metal used for the top and bottom of the can costs 4 cents per square inch, while material for the side of the can costs only 2 cents per square inch.

What is the DIAMETER of the can that has minimum cost?

Comment: I solved for V in terms of diameter and height. And I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Then I took that equation (V = pi(1/2D)^2h) and wrote it in terms of h...

Comment: h = 60/(1/2 D^2)

Answer (score 1):

The volume of a cylinder is

$$
V=\pi r^2h.
$$

The surface area of a cylinder is

$$
A=2\pi r^2+2\pi rh.
$$

In this problem, we seek to minimize $f$ subject to $g$, where

$$\begin{align}
f(r,h)&=8\pi r^2+4\pi rh,\quad\text{and}\\
g(r,h)&=\pi r^2h=60\pi.
\end{align}$$

Using the [method of Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), we have that:

$$\begin{align}
\nabla f&=\left\langle16\pi r+4\pi h,4\pi r\right\rangle,\quad\text{and}\\
\nabla g&=\left\langle2\pi rh,\pi r^2\right\rangle;
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
16\pi r+4\pi h&=\lambda2\pi rh,\\
4\pi r&=\lambda\pi r^2,\\
\pi r^2h&=60\pi;
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
h&=16/\lambda,\\
r&=4/\lambda,\\
\lambda&=4/\sqrt[3]{15}.
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $r=\sqrt[3]{15}$, and $d=2\sqrt[3]{15}$, as required.